# How to reach out the trader through the bitcoin address?

Tags: fraud, lost-bitcoins

I am actually a person who keenly watching and wondering the growth of bitcoin in recent days, when I was looking for an alternative business plan one of an Instagrammer pinged me and checked my interest in doing forex trading, we used to communicate through WA, her number is given below

Though I had no prior experience she was ready to help me in forex trading,

Initially, Invested 200$ followed her instructions, my trade account has been created in "https://en.cryptsmarket247.com/public/" and my bitcoin wallet has been created in "Wazirx". not sure it was a scam but my trade account reached $780, and still it is showing the figure and unable to withdraw.

She was claiming that my account reached $10000k and I need to pay $250 as a migration fee to withdraw the money, I paid $250, and once paid she started telling me that the money has not reflected on her company account. I was asked to pay one more $250 not to lose the already paid $250 and the profit $10k.

As I was new to trade and bitcoin I trusted her and paid another $250. she told me I would be receiving $250 in 30 mins $10k in 3 days and left as usual, but, from today onwards I could not see her in WA.

I could see where the bitcoin deposited at her end but not able to do anything, I raised a complaint with FTC and reported the issue at "https://bitcoinwhoswho.com/", is there any way I could recover my money back or I could reach her with the below details?

Her mobile number
Mobile number : +1 (819) 800-6746, +1 (364) 202-6061
Bitcoin Address: 3R2XQzyAqbzCmAsDX4tEjX5bm3SmusKym2
Her image attached (she claimed that she is the one in the image)

[image]

I am sure she is not a techie, so there any way I could block her bitcoin address?
any idea on the website I have given "https://en.cryptsmarket247.com/"

Someone, please help me!

Regards,
Raaamuz

Comment: Sorry, you lost your money. It's doubtful the scammer gave a real photo, and there's no real way to find the person based on a bitcoin address. Just learn from this lesson.

Comment: Yes! I lost my money, she didn't come back